# remove all UIButton's from subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

i'm programmatically adding a couple UIButtons to my view. After clicking one of the buttons they all should be 'removeFromSuperView' or released, not just one.

```
for (int p=0; p<[array count]; p++) {  
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,44,44)];  
    button.tag = p;  
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    [self.view addSubview:button];    
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
}
```

Now this is the part where all buttons should be removed. Not just one.

```
-(void) action:(id)sender{  
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;  
    int pressed = button.tag;  
    [button removeFromSuperview];  
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this one!

Answer (score 8):

A more efficient way would be to add each button to an array when you create it, and then when a button is pressed, have all the buttons in the array call the `-removeFromSuperView` method like this:

```
[arrayOfButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```

Then after that, you can either keep the buttons in the array and reuse them, or call `removeAllObjects` to have them released. Then you can start populating it again later.

This saves you from having to walk through the entire view hierarchy looking for buttons.

Comment: really clean idea. i did that always, with an extra view and then performing this "makeObjectsPerformSelector:" to that view. but doing this with an array is much better.

Answer (score 8):

Another answer just for reference:

```
for (int i = [self.view.subviews count] -1; i>=0; i--) {
    if ([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [buttonsToRemove addObject:subview];
    }
}
[buttonsToRemove makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

**EDIT**:
I have edited my answer to a better solution.
Now the objects are not removed from the array while enumerating it...

Comment: it should read "for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)" I guess

Comment: Thnx Micheal! After changing (UIView *subview in self.view) in: (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) it works like a charm!

Comment: @Felix, thank you for the correction. You are absolutely right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is bad advice. Apple clearly states that while using Fast Enumeration you should *not* modify the collection's contents. See http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Also try this it's very simple :

```
 for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews){     
              [btn removeFromSuperview]; //remove buttons
    }
```

Comment: as St3fan said, while using fast enumeration you SHOULD NOT modify the collection's content.